# scaling div to show the rest text in a div on mouseOver

Tags: css

i think my problem is a kind of customized problem i am trying to show the text(paragraph text) in a div When i hover on it. 
 I used scale property but i cant find the logic how to hide the text and on hover it will scale vertically showing the rest of the text in a div without disturbing the  rest of div
here is my code :

```
    <div class="middle">

     <div class="product1" id="product1" style="float: left;">


         <img src="res/images/product.png" width="300" height="180">

         <h3 class="prd_header">Custom Software</h3>

         <p class="paragraph"><b>Your ultimate destination for the outstanding desktop and web-based business applications</b>FEnD Consultants offers Custom software Development for Web and desktop applications. Our custom software development services help the modern-day enterprise keep pace with the rapidly.

</p>

     </div>
</div>
```

i have put little text  but my real text pretty long .

Here is my Css code :

```
.middle{
    height:730px;
    width: 100%;
    bord er-bottom:  1px dotted green ;
    margin-top: 50px;


}

#product1{


     opacity: 0.5;
     transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;

}
#product1:hover{



    background: #e0e0e0;

    opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1.1.1);
          transform: scale(1.1.1.1);
}
.middle p {

    text-align: left;

}
```

Comment: The `scale` in transform uses commas `,` and not dots `.` and you can at most supply 2 values (x,y).

Comment: What Niklas said... see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#scale

Comment: @xec ,@niklas i was new to sacle property i saw dots maybe i couldnt get it well

Comment: you can use decimal points, so `scale(1.1,1.1)` will be valid (same as `scale(1.1)` as both values are the same) and scale both axis to 110%

Comment: As I re-read the question, I'm not so sure you want to scale at all, maybe you just want to animate the height of the container to create a slide-down effect revealing the text? Is that what you meant? http://jsfiddle.net/A29G4/2/ - mind you, this will be difficult to do without static heights

Comment: @xec  sorry for inconvenience my question means as my div have long text i want to show some text and hide rest of it , i want to scale the div vertically to it will create some space to show the hidden text(<p>)

Comment: I posted an answer, can you check the demo link to see if something like that is what you are after?

Comment: @Snow_ash - Did you solve this question? If you did, you should mark someones answer or post your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The scale in transform uses commas `,` and not dots `.` and you can at most supply 2 values `(x,y)`.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A29G4/1/) of your code.

*Here are some examples and explanations, concerning your comment.*

`scale(2.2)` means `scale(x)`

`scale(2,2)` means `scale(x,y)`

`scale(2.2, 1.1)` means `scale(x, y)`

Do you see the difference? You can precis the x and y values with decimals, but you can only have one decimal point for each value. Check @xec's comment to read more about this.

Comment: can you suggest me which logic i should apply to hide some of text of paragraph and on Hover div will scale + hidden text(<p>) should be visible ?

Comment: @xec you have gone close to my solution.  It will like  be some text of paragraph will be shown and on hover div height will change and (Take another paragraph which i will hide it )<p style="visiblity:none">some data </p> will be shown. i will apply that jquery script on this paragraph

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure you want to scale at all, maybe you just want to animate the height of the container to create a slide-down effect revealing the text? Is that what you meant?

#### css alternative

If so you could do so with the following css (assuming you know what the heights of the div should be)

```css
#product1 {
    height: 200px; /* height of div excluding the paragraph */
    overflow: hidden; /* hide anything below */
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
#product1:hover {
    height: 320px; /* reveal paragraph by resizing the container */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A29G4/2/

#### javascript alternative

If you want the height of the paragraph (and other content) to be dynamic, you are probably better off letting jQuery do the math for you;

```js
var paragraph = $(".paragraph");
$(".product1").hover(function () {
    paragraph.slideDown();
}, function () {
    paragraph.slideUp();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A29G4/3/

Comment: This is the best answer for this question =)

Comment: thanks for paying attention to my problem. excellent work and it  helps me clearing my concepts about scale